# Intellij IDEA 2021.2.2 (Ultimate Edition) cannot read jdk8 source

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

1. IDEA version:
   [image]
2. OS version:
   Windows 10 19045.3208
3. Problems:
   Idea decompiles the class automatically instead of reading the source when I ctrl + click the String.java
   [image]
4. Idea setting:
   [image]

Comment: Try do download the JDK right from the IDE. Go to `File | Project Structure | SDKs` Click `+ | Download JDK` After downloading was finished setup this JDK under `File | Project Structure | Project` and click OK. Wait for the indexing to be completed and try to navigate

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing jdk8 in WSL2.0

[image]